# SPFx: pnp.sp.search how to get all assosiated sites using hub site name

Tags: search, spfx, pnp

I making simple SPFx. I need to return all associated sites by using hub site name (not hub site id), I have example with hub id

```
 sp.search({
  RowLimit: 40,
  StartRow: 0,
  SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType","Department"],
  QueryTemplate: "contentclass: STS_Site AND DepartmentId:1111*",
})
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?